# Summation with factorial

Tags: summation, factorial

I want to understand how this step is performed.
Can you tell me that how this value of Po is obtained from the first equation.!

$$P_o=\frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{\alpha}{u}\right)^k\frac{1}{k!}}$$

$$P_o=e^{-\frac{\alpha}{u}}$$

Comment: It's rather unreadable. Could you type it?

Comment: Is it better now.?

Comment: It appears false to me. Can't see all that well, but it appears that where there is multiplication by $k!$, it would need to instead be division.

Comment: yes sorry, it is 1/k!

Comment: I've edited it and now it is 1/k!.

Answer (score 2):

$$P_o=\frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{\alpha}{u}\right)^k.\frac{1}{k!}}$$

Substitute $\frac{\alpha}{u}=x$.

The denominator is  $$f(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots$$

Notice that this is the Taylor expansion for $e^x$, and this yields the answer.
$$f(x)=e^x$$
$$P_0= \frac{1}{f(x)} = e^{-\frac{\alpha}{u}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much Arpan. God bless you.

Comment: Well... Thanks, I guess :)